# javascript inheritance. How to extend a class

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, extends

I'm working on a chess game. I want to make an abstract piece class, which then can be extended by pawn/knight/rook/etc. Let's say my piece class looks like this:

```
"use strict";
function Piece(color) {
    this.color = color;
    this.type = "Abstract";
}
Piece.prototype.sayName = function sayName(){
    alert(this.type);
}
Piece.prototype.movePiece(oldPosition, newPosition){
};
```

I'd instantiate it like so:

```
var abstractPiece = new Piece("Black");
```

Now let's say I want to make a Pawn class that I'd like to instantiate as follows.

```
var pawnOne = new Pawn("Black");
```

I want Pawn to have the same sayName function, but I want it to have a different movePiece function, because Pawns have their own unique way of moving. How would I make Pawn, such that it extends Piece, and has overwritten Piece's movePiece function?

Comment: Could you write it so Piece never needs a move function? I'm thinking all the chess pieces have pretty unique allowed moves, so there is no reason to ever define move and then also overload it.

Comment: Possibly. I actually already have every piece working, but there's a lot of shared code because I couldn't figure out how to extend an abstract class.

Even if this is possible, I'm asking because I want to know how to do this.

Comment: Also, you should consider reading the relateds and maybe click the javascript tag and go to the tag wiki and read through some of that, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd define a piece slightly differently to make it more extendable.

```
var Piece = function(color) {
    return {
        color : color,
        type : "Abstract",
        sayName : function sayName(){
            alert(this.type);
        },
        movePiece : function(oldPosition, newPosition){
        }
    };
}

var Pawn = function(color) {
    var pawn = Piece("Black");
    pawn.movePiece = function(oldPosition, newPosition) { 
        // pawn move here 
    };
    return pawn;
}
```

You can then create a piece or a pawn by doing `Piece("Black")` or `Pawn("Black")`.

Comment: Can you explain why this is more extendable?

Comment: This seems like a good strategy. If I were to add a function to pawn called movePiece, would it override the movePiece function in Piece? Hypothetically, since there will be no Piece that actually is instantiated and needs to move, I could take it out of Piece, but hypothetically if I wanted to override that function could I?

Comment: Extendable might not be the best word.  The reason I prefer this style is because it confines the class definition to one location, rather than wherever one puts the `prototype` calls, and it avoids the use of `new`.  Also, I don't specifically know how prototyped functions conflict with specifically set properties, so this avoids that (though I'll have to remember to look that up).

Comment: Because `Piece()` returns an object, you can override the `movePiece` property and everything will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution for that,

As another generic solution, I attached a function to the default javascript super Function. Then it will be applied for the all javascript instances.

```
Function.prototype.extend=function(superClass){
    for (var property in superClass.prototype){
        if(property!='extend' && property!='type' && !this.prototype[property]){
            this.prototype[property] = superClass.prototype[property];
        }
    }
}
```

Above code should be applied very first before load any javascript.

Then you can use it like this.

```
//Super class constructor
function Collection(){
    this.type = 'Collection';   
}

//sub class
function HashSet(){
    this.type='HashSet';
    HashSet.extend(Collection);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Matt's answer, I would also have each specific type call the 'base' logic of movePiece by simply providing a different name, as show below:

```
var Pawn = function(color) {
    var pawn = Piece("Black");
    pawn.movePawn = function(oldPosition, newPosition) { 
        // special pawn-specific logic for moving here
        // now call 'base' logic to actually move piece to the new position
        pawn.prototype.movePiece(oldPosition, newPosition);
    };
    return pawn;
}
```

This will allow all pieces to share the same logic for actually moving to a new spot on the board, but also allow for custom logic depending on the type of piece.

Answer (score -1):

When you extend classes in Coffeescript, the compiler generates code that "extends" one JS class with another. I got this:

```
var Animal, Dog, _ref,
  __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
  __extends = function(child, parent) {
     // This function takes a child class and extends it with all
     // attributes that are included in the parent class.
     for (var key in parent) {
         // Need to check that this property was actually a key of the parent.
         // The Coffeescript compiler was defensive here against changes to
         // the hasOwnProperty function, but you can probably get by with
         // parent.hasOwnProperty(key).
         if (__hasProp.call(parent, key))
             child[key] = parent[key];
     }
     function ctor() {
         this.constructor = child;
     }
     // Set the default constructor of the child based on the parents.
     ctor.prototype = parent.prototype;
     child.prototype = new ctor();
     // Make it possible to call the __super__ easily.
     child.__super__ = parent.prototype;
     return child;
 };

Animal = (function() {
  function Animal() {}

  // To add methods to this class, you would do this:
  //   Animal.prototype.foo = function() {...}

  return Animal;

})();

Dog = (function(_super) {
  __extends(Dog, _super);

  function Dog() {
    _ref = Dog.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    // This is where you would extend the constructor to add
    // functionality to the subclass.
    return _ref;
  }

  // To add methods to this subclass, or to override base class
  // methods, you would do this:
  //   Dog.prototype.bar = function() {...}

  return Dog;

})(Animal);
```

by typing

```
class Animal

class Dog extends Animal
```

into the compiler at http://coffeescript.org/, and then commenting the result.

Comment: Output from a compiler is not a good way to explain something.

Comment: I've seen this for both CoffeeScript and TypeScript. Extending it like that seems so ridiculously complicated it's not worth it. I assumed it's partly because it's compiled code instead of handwritten. I guess I'm convinced there is a better way. I'm ready to be wrong.

Comment: @MattBryant you're absolutely right. I've gone through that code and commented it. A lot of the compiled output (ex: _ref and __hasOwn) is just defensive and could be dropped if you're doing this by hand.